# TikZ arc with extreme angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

In TikZ, I want this curve to bend around the ellipse. But no matter how high I set the angle, it would not bend that far. Is there a way to do it?

[image: curve]

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw[fill=black] (6,8) circle  [radius=0.1];
\draw (6,6.2) ellipse (2.5cm and 0.7cm);
\draw[fill=black] (6,4.5) circle  [radius=0.1];
\draw[->] (6,4.5) to[bend left=80] (5.9,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @SandyG Corrected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add `looseness` to the draw command:

`\draw[->] (6,4.5) to[bend left=80, looseness=2.7] (5.9,8);`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For `coordinate`s or `node`s `A` and `B`, to get **full control** of a curve from `A` to `B`, use `controls`

```
\draw (A) .. controls +(<out shooting angle>:<out shooting force>) and +(<in shooting angle>:<in shooting force>) .. (B);
```

I improve your code: use `node` instead of `coordinate`, so you don't need to manual adjust in order to the arrow touching the dot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}]
\path (0,2) node[dot] (U) {} (0,-2) node[dot] (L) {};
\draw (0,0) ellipse(2.5 and .7);
\draw[->,red] (L) .. controls +(170:2) and +(-170:2) .. (U);
\draw[->,blue] (L) .. controls +(45:3) and +(-45:3) .. (U);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The bigger in/out shouting forces, the further distance is. When using big shouting forces, to make bounding box not larger, use `\clip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=2pt}]
\clip (-4,-2.5) rectangle (4,2.5);     % to make bounding box not larger (when using big shouting forces).

\path (0,2) node[dot] (U) {} (0,-2) node[dot] (L) {};
\draw (0,0) ellipse(2.5 and .7);

% the bigger in/out shouting forces
\draw[-stealth,red] (L) .. controls +(170:4) and +(-170:4) .. (U);
\draw[-stealth,blue] (L) .. controls +(35:6) and +(-35:6) .. (U);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe add/change your examples to include a case which "bend[s] around the ellipse"? Otherwise, one could get the impression that `controls` could not satisfy that request. E.g. `+(170:4)` works for me.

Comment: I added an update. Thanks @ojdo !

Answer (score 0):

I add this line with `left =-80`

```
\draw[->] (6,4.5) to[bend left=-80] (5.9,8);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzset{>={Latex[width=2mm,length=2mm]}}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.7]
\draw[fill=black] (6,8) circle  [radius=0.1];
\draw (6,6.2) ellipse (2.5cm and 0.7cm);
\draw[fill=black] (6,4.5) circle  [radius=0.1];
\draw[-] (6,4.5) to[bend left=80] (5.9,8);
\draw[<-] (6,4.5) to[bend left=-80] (5.9,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can display or not  the circles  (6,6.2) and (5.9,8) by adding a comment %

Comment: Why did you undo the edit that made your post readable?

Comment: I don't think that answers OP's question. You may delete your post for the sake of clearness.

Comment: The question may not have been totally clear, but this is not what the OP meant by bending around the ellipse.