# Specifying an Arc in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I'm trying to learn to use Tikz via the tutorial [here](https://tikz.dev/tutorial).

**Section 2.4** (Curved Path Construction) says that we draw a curve as follows:

> The next thing Karl wants to do is to draw the circle. For this,
> straight lines obviously will not do. Instead, we need some way to
> draw curves. For this, TikZ provides a special syntax. One or two
> “control points” are needed. The math behind them is not quite
> trivial, but here is the basic idea: Suppose you are at point x and the
> first control point is y. Then the curve will start “going in the
> direction of y at x”, that is, the tangent of the curve at will point
> toward y. Next, suppose the curve should end at z and the second support
> point is w. Then the curve will, indeed, end at z and the tangent of the
> curve at point z will go through w.

The author gives the following example, in which he draws the upper half of the unit circle.

```
     \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw (-1.5,0) -- (1.5,0);
     \draw (0,-1.5) -- (0,1.5);
     \draw (-1,0) .. controls (-1,0.555) and (-0.555,1) .. (0,1)
                   .. controls (0.555,1) and (1,0.555) .. (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This "control point" method seems really vague and confusing. Can anyone provide a link or other information about how this actually works?

Comment: This tutorial is from the manual. Great manual, but bad tutorial in my opinion. This is not how to draw a half circle - use `arc` - also in the tutorial. Learn about control points for a bezier curve: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bézier_curve

Comment: The line through `(-1,0)` and `(-1,0.5555)` **is** the line `x = -1`.  But note that tangents in the sense of curves have both magnitude and direction, so it's not enough to specify the tangent _line_ but also you need to specify a point on that line.  That's what the `(-1,0.5555)` is.

Comment: Take it easy and take it simple! In pgfmanual the meaning and the TikZ syntax of `controls` are clear. From `(A)` we shoot forward, from `(B)` we shoot backward `\draw (A) .. controls +(<out shooting angle>:<out shooting force>) and +(<in shooting angle>:<in shooting force>) .. (B);` https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638015/140722
`